# GitKraken how to reopen merged branch with the same name

Tags: git, branch, gitkraken

I created the branch `b1` from `master`. After some commites pull-request was created, approved, merged into `master` and deleted. But I still have `b1` on local machine, which I dont't want to delete. And now I want to reopen branch with the same name `b1` from master, but `GitKraken` throws an error:

> Cannot create the ref because it already exists.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two different branches with the same name.

You can either delete your existing branch : since it was merged into master, the complete history of this branch should be part of `master` anyway,
or you can rename the existing branch on your local clone :

```
# choose any suitable target name :
git branch -m b1 archived/b1
```

and create a new `b1` branch from wherever you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
I was confused, because when I worked with `TortoiseHg` I could reopen closed, but not deleted branches